# error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

I'm calling `git checkout HEAD~2 "Finished 1 stage"` (or just `git checkout "Finished 1 stage"`)

Then i get `error: pathspec 'Finished 1 stage' did not match any file(s) known to git`

git log:[git log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRWEE.png)

I'm trying to get files from commit "Finished 1 stage"

I hope you will help me!

Comment: Are you trying to list the files that are in that commit or trying to checkout that commit and work on those files?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get files from commit "Finished 1 stage"

In Git, commits are *numbered*, as a big long ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number.  What `git checkout` or `git restore` actually *needs* here is the commit's *number*.  So at the raw level you might write:

```
git checkout a123456
```

This means *switch to that (entire) commit* (as a "detached HEAD"); your working tree will then consist of files from that commit, plus any untracked files that Git does not touch, that remain in place from before.<sup>1</sup>

If you only want some *particular files* from that particular commit, the best—as in safest—way to express that is:

```
git checkout a123456 -- path/to/file1.ext name/of/file2.ext
```

for instance.  Note that this request means *destroy any unsaved work I have in these two files* and Git will do that without asking.  The two dashes here, `--`, separate the *commit specifier* `a123456` from the two path names.  If you *omit* the two dashes, Git assumes them, *as long as the file names do not resemble option specifiers or similar*.  For instance, suppose you want to get a file named `-b`.  The name `-b` also looks like the *option* `-b`.  The two dashes help Git be sure that something *is* an option (if it's on the left side of the `--`) or *isn't* an option (if it's on the right side of the `--`).

Now, those big ugly hash IDs are hard to type.  You can use `git log` to find the commit you want, then use the mouse to cut-and-paste the hash ID.  But that's still not very pretty.  Sometimes it might be nice to use something other than a big ugly hash ID, or even an abbreviated one like `a123456`.  Your use of `HEAD~2` is a way to avoid having to type in the hash ID.

If `HEAD~2` *names* that commit—which it might—then `HEAD~2` is *all you need* and is *all you should enter*.  The commit's subject text, such as "Finished 1 stage", *should not be included* here.

To see the hash ID from `HEAD~2`, you can run `git rev-parse`.  This command isn't all that interesting except in terms of illustrating how `git checkout` turns the string `HEAD~2` into a hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD~2
7652ce966f9b398e02a5df0344d015c4d54ca52a
```

(your results will differ).  To get a better look at the commit, consider using `git show`:

```
$ git show HEAD~2
```

(output not included here).

There *are* ways to use the log messages to search for a commit.  These are described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which is worth repeated reading over time.  But if `HEAD~2` suffices, you should probably just use that.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a special case for files that you have modified but not yet committed.  For the gory details, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
git checkout HEAD~2
```

then you checkout to the commit which is 2 commits behind HEAD which is the head of the branch. You probably just need the command above.

Your error message suggests that "Finished 1 stage" is a not existing file. Apparently that's a commit message, that's unnecessarily passed and git interprets

```
git checkout HEAD~2 "Finished 1 stage"
```

as

> checkout to HEAD~2, but only for the file called "Finished 1 stage"